# LINQ to Entities / LINQ to SQL: switching from server (queryable) to client (enumerable) in the middle of a query comprehension?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

In many cases, I want to do some filtering (and sometimes projection) on the server side and then switch to client-side for operations that the LINQ provider doesn't natively support.

The naive approach (which is basically what I do now) is to just break it up into multiple queries, similar to:

```
var fromServer = from t in context.Table
                 where t.Col1 = 123
                 where t.Col2 = "blah"
                 select t;

var clientSide = from t in fromServer.AsEnumerable()
                 where t.Col3.Split('/').Last() == "whatever"
                 select t.Col4;
```

However, there are many times where this is more code/trouble than it's really worth.  I'd really like to do a 'switch to client side' in the middle. I've tried various methods of using a query continuation, but after doing a 'select t into foo' at the end of the first query, foo is still an individual item, not the collection, so I can't AsEnumerable() it.

My goal is to be able write something more like:

```
var results = from t in context.Table
              where t.Col1 = 123
              where t.Col2 = "blah"
              // Magic happens here to switch to the client side
              where t.Col3.Split('/').Last() == "whatever"
              select t.Col4;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, firstly you absolutely *should not use the code here*. It was written by trained stunt-hamsters who have been trained not to throw up when dealing with this code of this nature.

You should *absolutely* pick one of the options you know about:

- Use a "temporary" variable (if you can statically type that variable as `IEnumerable<T>` then you don't need the call to `AsEnumerable` - that won't work if you've got an anonymous type as the element type of course)
- Use brackets for a call to `AsEnumerable`
- Use the "fluent" or "dot notation" syntax to make the `AsEnumerable` call fit in.

However, you *can* do a bit of magic, using the way that query expressions are translated. You just need to make one of the standard query operators with a representation in query expressions have a different translation. The simplest option here is probably "Where". Just write your own extension method taking an `IQueryable<T>` and a `Func<T, SomeType>` where `SomeType` isn't `bool`, and you're away. Here's an example, first of the hack itself and then a sample use of it...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class QueryHacks
{
    public static readonly HackToken TransferToClient = HackToken.Instance;

    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> source,
        Func<T, HackToken> ignored)
    {
        // Just like AsEnumerable... we're just changing the compile-time
        // type, effectively.
        return source;
    }

    // This class only really exists to make sure we don't *accidentally* use
    // the hack above.
    public class HackToken
    {
        internal static readonly HackToken Instance = new HackToken();
        private HackToken() {}
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Pretend this is really a db context or whatever
        IQueryable<string> source = new string[0].AsQueryable();

        var query = from x in source
                    where x.StartsWith("Foo") // Queryable.Where
                    where QueryHacks.TransferToClient
                    where x.GetHashCode() == 5 // Enumerable.Where
                    select x.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Warnings will be ignored, this code I will see out there in the wild. Thanks for letting me know in advance.

Comment: If you're going to say it's bad, then you really should explain *why* it's bad, or else people are going to use it.  To be honest, I'm not 100% sure it's that bad myself if you choose a suitable naming convention and you're consistent about usage, and would enjoy being enlightened by the chosen one.

Comment: @Scott: It's completely non-idiomatic, it's using the where clause in a way which is clearly *not* what it's designed for (we're not filtering at all here) - it's an abuse all round. It works, and it's guaranteed to work, but it's still not nice.

Comment: @Jon: right, so it's just because it's doing something other than filtering, and a "where" should only filter.  I buy that.  So if linq contained a new keyword: "evalute" or something, then it would be OK?

Comment: Saddened to see this far outranking better answers, lets not super rank answers just because they are 'interesting' or more likely because they are Jon Skeet answers, it ruins the whole point of the site.

Comment: @meandmycode: [Part 1] FWIW, I actually begged Jon to chime in after seeing the other answers which, IMHO, added nothing of value: one does 'inline variable', another is a method-chain answer even though the question is explicitly about query comprehension syntax, David's isn't really an answer to the question IMHO.  I didn't feel like any of them added anything, just saying basically 'no, you cannot do that'.

Comment: @meandmycode: [Part 2] I asked for Jon to chime in because I feel he's among the (small) set of people with enough LINQ expertise to answer authoritatively.  He even gives a viable method of doing so (even if it's bad engineering practice, which he both pointed out and then explained why), when all other answers were saying 'cannot be done at all'.  I agree that upvotes/answers shouldn't be assigned based on SO/internet/whatever popularity, but I've re-read all the answers and I don't see how of the others are as good as Jon's (the only one with a viable alternative), let alone better.

Comment: It hasn't anything to do really with you asking him to answer or not, purely those who decide to vote for answers, I was wrong when I said answers though, there is one good answer that should have been the accepted, promoted way to handle the scenario.

Answer (score 8):

Of course, if you were using the normal method syntax, this would be no problem:

```
var results = context.Table
              .Where(t => t.Col1 == 123)
              .Where(t => t.Col2 == "blah")
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Where(t => t.Col3.Split('/').Last() == "whatever")
              .Select(t => t.Col4);
```

If you insist on using the query syntax, you won’t get around using some parentheses, but otherwise, you can certainly still do the same:

```
var results = from t in (
                  from t in context.Table
                  where t.Col1 == 123
                  where t.Col2 == "blah"
                  select t
              ).AsEnumerable()
              where t.Col3.Split('/').Last() == "whatever"
              select t.Col4;
```

<sup><sub>Reusing the variable name `t` does not cause any problems; I tested it.</sub></sup>

Comment: Good point, I should have made that more clear - certainly I could 'inline' the fromServer variable with parens (as you've done here), but that's part of what I was hoping to avoid (if it's possible, which it may not be).in the 'theoretical' case, the parts above/below the '// magic happens here to switch to client side' should ideally stay as-is (although if the range variable needs to change name after the switch, that's fine).

Comment: @James: I’ve listed your options in my answer. I can’t pull something out of my hat that doesn’t exist ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by server/client side?

I guess you mean you get some collection from the server and then execute additional filtering that's is not available in the LINQ-to-entity. Just try this:

```
var items =
    context.Table.Where(t => t.Col1 = 123 && t.Col2 = "blah").ToList()
    .Where(t => t.Col3.Split('/').Last() == "whatever")
    .Select(t => t.Col4).ToList();
```

Comment: Using `ToList` certainly works, but introduces an unnecessary inefficiency. The second `ToList` is probably redundant.

Comment: Indeed, for the method-chaining version, I could call .AsEnumerable() to do the switch (which is what I do in the first version in the question).  ToList will also have a similar effect, but less efficiently as it will require creating/populating a list only to have it thrown away with the .Where right afterwards (which is why I would use AsEnumerable instead)

Comment: agreed, you can replace ToList for more efficiency

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the more abstract syntax to gain finer control over server vs local execution?  Sorry - that's not do-able.

Think about the problem of scope within the query comprehension.

```
from c in context.Customers
from o in c.Orders
from d in o.Details
asLocal
where //c, o and d are all in scope, so they all had to be hydrated locally??
```

Comment: if you didn't filter before your theoretical 'asLocal' keyword, then yes, they'd all be local (which is why the scenario has filtering done server-side first).  If your server-side filtering had only 1 'd' (and therefore one parent 'o' for it and one parent 'c' for that), then I really don't see what the problem is with them all being in scope.  Alternatively, since the query comprehension syntax obviously translates to the method-chain syntax, you can consider the question ('what options are available to "reverse" AsEnumerable into a query comprehension?')