# Is it possible to extend the Query-Keywords in C# / LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, select

is it possible to extend the query-keywords of Linq (like: select, where, etc.) with own definitions?

Codeexample to make it clearer:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> aList = 
    new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { "aa", "ab", "ba", "bb" };

// instead of
string firstString = (from item in aList
                      where item.StartsWith("a")
                      select item).First();

// would be nice
string firstString = from item in aList
                     where item.StartsWith("a")
                     selectFirst item;

// or something else
from item in aList
where item.StartsWith("a")
WriteLineToConsole item;
```

I think it's not possible, but still hoping ;)

Comment: Any particular reason why would you want to do this?

Comment: Three 400K+ users answered your question. Go, slaughter a goat!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to write a pre-processor which will transform your custom LINQ keywords into standard LINQ keywords before feeding it to the compiler. By the way that's how it works with the standard LINQ keywords. A pre-processor converts them into normal extension methods (.Select, .Where, .GroupBy, ...), and then feeds it to the compiler which doesn't understand those keywords.

Of course by doing this you will lose Intellisense, but this could be solved by writing a Visual Studio extension. Could be quite a lot of work though for this sugar.

Comment: Know that it's a very old question, but have you managed to do something about the custom keywords?

Answer (score 8):

You can't add your own contextual keywords, but you *can* affect what the existing ones mean.

For example, this code:

```
string firstString = (from item in aList
                      where item.StartsWith("a")
                      select item).First();
```

is effectively preprocessed to:

```
string firstString = aList.Where(item => item.StartsWith("a"))
                          .First();
```

... so if you change what those `Where` and `First` method calls mean, you can affect the behaviour.

If you've got the stomach for it, you might want to look at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824367/linq-to-entities-linq-to-sql-switching-from-server-queryable-to-client-enum/4825734#4825734) I wrote a while ago which changes the behaviour of `where` in LINQ to Entities in certain circumstances. It's evil, evil code though.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible within the language spec or any current C# compiler. Anything you create there would no longer be (pure) C#.